# flipping the names around in php

Tags: php

ok so i have a user field that has the user enter the full name and i need to flip the names around

```
 $pieces = explode(" ", $_POST['realname']);
 name = stripslashes($pieces[1] . "-" . $pieces[0]);
```

but the problem is that if they type in the field

i need the final output as jones-mark for sake of the requirements or if there is only mark then i need mark

```
mark jones
```

all is well but if they type

```
mark
```

then the output is

```
-mark
```

im sure there is a better way to do this

Comment: use `implode('-', array_reverse($pieces))` instead

Comment: If the users name is "William John Parker Stones", do you expect the output to be "stones-parker-john-willian" or do you only want to swap first names with family names like "parker-stone-william-john"?

Comment: just first and last name

Answer (score 4):

`implode("-",array_reverse($pieces))`